# open difrent contents in popup window

Tags: javascript, html

This code is working and all, but both links are opening the same info, which is the info of link2   `

## POP2

, . If i remove the second link, the first one opens without problem. What am i missing ?

HTML

```js
 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $('.open').click(function() {
        $('.pop_background').fadeIn();
        $('.pop_box').fadeIn();
        return false;
       });
        $('.close').click(function() {
        $('.pop_background').fadeOut();
        $('.pop_box').fadeOut();
        return false;
    
      });
    
        $('.pop_background').click(function(){
        $('.pop_background').fadeOut();
        $('.pop_box').fadeOut();
        return false;
         });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="responsive1">
     <div class="pop_background"></div>
    <div class="pop_box">
      <h1>POP1</h1>
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
      <div class="img">
        <a class="open" href="#">
          click to open pop
        </a>
       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="responsive1">
     <div class="pop_background"></div>
    <div class="pop_box">
      <h1>POP2</h1>
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
      <div class="img">
        <a class="open" href="#">
          click to open pop2
        </a>
       
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I started a [codepen](http://codepen.io/AnotherLinuxUser/pen/oYNrRX), but without the css it's harder to know what you expect. Also, do you really need jquery for this?

Comment: The problem is quite simple: You're using the class names as selectors in Javascript. Since both "pop" and "pop2" have the same class names, Javascript has no way knowing which one you want. It can't differentiate between them.

Comment: yes, i imagined that's the problem... the simple to solution if i'm not wrong, is to duplicate the js and the css for each popup... =\

Comment: If this is jQuery, please tag as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes are all referencing the same object. You have to assign IDs to each.

***Update:*** I have created a javascript function to accept the parameters which is the container id so you can call it once. Its at the bottom of this answer

**HTML**

```
<div id="pb1" class="pop_box">
  <h1>POP1</h1>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
</div>
  <div class="img">
    <a id="openpb1" class="open" href="#">
      click to open pop1
    </a>

<div id="pb2" class="pop_box">
  <h1>POP2</h1>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
</div>
  <div class="img">
    <a id="openpb2" class="open" href="#">
      click to open pop2
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

Repeat the code for pop2

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#openpb1').click(function() {
    $('#pb1').fadeIn();
    $('.pop_box').fadeIn();
    return false;
   });
    $('#pb1 .close').click(function() {
    $('#pb1').fadeOut();
    $('#pb1').fadeOut();
    return false;

  });

    $('.pop_background').click(function(){
    $('.pop_background').fadeOut();
    $('.pop_box').fadeOut();
    return false;
     });
});
</script>
```

**Using it as a function**

```
<script>    
   function myPopup(container){
        $(container).fadeIn();
        $('.pop_box').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }

$('#openpb1').click(function() {
myPopup('#pb1');
});

$('#openpb2').click(function() {
myPopup('#pb2');
});    
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, i ended up to try that solution, repeting the code for each individual pop. it will be quite tedious if one has to code a considerable number of popUps ... but it works....

Comment: If the above solution worked then you should mark it as answer. Its the only way around it else you will keep refrencing same object all the time.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have only written the JavaScript for the first pop-up? You are not telling the computer which pop-up it should open.